chess game: loading images for the rooks
I was ok with my pawn code but the rook code is very long and I want it to make the code shorter and cleaner and the same thing with my bishops, knights, kings and queens.
rook_image = piece_images["white_rook"]
rook_x = checkerboard.square_size // 2 + 150
rook_y = checkerboard.square_size + 55
win.blit(rook_image.image,
         (rook_x - rook_image.image.get_width() // 2, rook_y - rook_image.image.get_height() // 2))

rook_image_2 = piece_images["white_rook"]
rook_x_2 = checkerboard.square_size * 9.5
rook_y_2 = checkerboard.square_size + 55
win.blit(rook_image.image,
         (rook_x_2 - rook_image_2.image.get_width() // 2, rook_y_2 - rook_image_2.image.get_height() // 2))

black_rook = piece_images["black_rook"]
rook_x_black = checkerboard.square_size // 2 + 150
rook_y_black = (8 * checkerboard.square_size) + 55
win.blit(rook_image.image,
         (rook_x_black - black_rook.image.get_width() // 2,
          rook_y_black - black_rook.image.get_height() // 2))

black_rook_image_2 = piece_images["black_rook"]
black_rook_x_2 = checkerboard.square_size * 9.5
black_rook_y_2 = (8 * checkerboard.square_size) + 55
win.blit(rook_image.image,
         (black_rook_x_2 - black_rook_image_2.image.get_width() // 2,
          black_rook_y_2 - black_rook_image_2.image.get_height() // 2))


magic numbers
Give names to these constants, please: 9.5, 55, 150
two-level dict
Keys like "white_rook" and "black_rook" are not as convenient as they could be.
Prefer two levels:
from enum import Enum, auto

class Color(Enum):
    WHITE = auto()
    BLACK = auto()

player = Color.WHITE  # white gets the first move
rook_image = piece_images[player]["rook"]

You will also want each piece to be able to render itself.
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Piece:
    rank: int
    file: int
    name: str

    def render(self, win, player_images):
        win.blit(player_images[self.name].image,
                 get_screen_coords(self.file, self.rank))

You can write a simple helper to convert from small integer chess board
coordinates to the larger screen coordinates.
And you will want to write a few classes that inherit from Piece
and know about legal moves for knight, bishop, and so on.

Where do you get the get_screen_coords from?

IDK what grid scale and offset you want, but maybe SCALE = 50 px per square, OFFSET = 100, and then you could define the helper to return (file * SCALE + OFFSET, rank * SCALE + OFFSET), which as I suggested converts from small integer chess board coordinates to the larger screen coordinates.

@Voile, I was trying to meet the OP where they are. Baby steps, toward a better codebase. Please feel free to post an alternate Answer.

First of all; rook_image, rook_image_2, black_rook, black_rook_image_2, rook_image_2, etc. can be improved, although they are somewhat descriptive. Something like this might be better:
SCALE = ...
OFFSET = ...

def get_screen_coords(file, rank):
    return file * SCALE + OFFSET, rank * SCALE + OFFSET


for img, rank in (("white_rook", 0), ("black_rook", 7)):
    for file in (0, 7):
        win.blit(piece_images[img].image, get_screen_coords(file, rank))

However, an even better approach would be the object-oriented approach that @J_H highlighted. (Also, I don't know how you want to store your pieces, but presumably you want to manipulate them at some point, instead of just drawing them onto the screen.)
pieces = []

for name, rank in (("white_rook", 0), ("black_rook", 7)):
    for file in (0, 7):
        piece = Piece(rank=rank, file=file, name=name)
        piece.render(win, piece_images)
        pieces.append(piece)

You might also consider moving get_screen_coords into the Piece class, although this is more a matter of taste:
@dataclass
class Piece:
    rank: int
    file: int
    name: str

    # something like this
    @staticmethod
    def get_screen_coords(file, rank):
        return file * SCALE + OFFSET, rank * SCALE + OFFSET


    def render(self, win, piece_images):
        win.blit(piece_images[self.name].image,
                 self.get_screen_coords(self.file, self.rank))

Also, as you will probably be expanding this for all the pieces, you may want to store the piece image paths and positions as a constant:
PIECES = (
    (0, 0, "white_rook"),
    (0, 7, "white_rook"),
    (7, 0, "black_rook"),
    (7, 7, "black_rook")
)

pieces = []

for piece_data in PIECES:
    piece = Piece(*piece_data)
    piece.render(win, piece_images)
    pieces.append(piece)

or alternatively:
PIECES = (
    {"rank": 0, "file": 0, "name": "white_rook"},
    {"rank": 0, "file": 7, "name": "white_rook"},
    {"rank": 7, "file": 0, "name": "black_rook"},
    {"rank": 7, "file": 7, "name": "black_rook"}
)

pieces = []

for piece_data in PIECES:
    piece = Piece(**piece_data)
    piece.render(win, piece_images)
    pieces.append(piece)


You may even consider storing this data as a separate json file, which you then read and parse in your program.

Your answer seems fine to me. Not sure why you got a downvote.
